# JDBC GetConnection from AWS Lambda toward an RDS instance, too much time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm using JDBC to connect to my instance of RDS, here is the lambda code:

```
private static Connection connection;
@Override
public Object handleRequest(Object o, Context context) {
    try {
        if (connection == null) {
            initConnection();
        }
        System.out.println("Connection ok...");
        connection.close();
        System.out.println("Connection closed...");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new GatewayResponse("", buildHeaders(), 200);
}

private void initConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        System.out.println("Driver found...");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that on a cold start lambda invocation it takes about 20 seconds to connect, what do you suggest to reduce the connection time?

Comment: Starting up a lambda is slow, creating a database connection is slow.

Comment: It's slow using Java, because I've tried in NodeJS and Python and it works very fast :D

Comment: Yes, the JVM takes a while to warm up too. That's why it's not very suitable for an on-off type workload that lambdas often do.